# hiding a control which has focus in ms access 2007

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, combobox, ms-access-2007

I have a combobox on a form. Clicking on a particular label should hide this combobox. The problem is that if the combobox has focus, clicking on the button which hides this combobox gives error.How can I resolve this runtime error?

Answer (score 3):

Move the focus. If necessary, create a very small control to receive the focus.

```
Me.SomeControlThatIsNotTheCombobox.SetFocus
```

Re Comments

Note that this label is not associated with a control.

```
Private Sub Label1_Click()
   Me.Text1.SetFocus
   Me.Label1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Use a tiny textbox with a transparent bg and no one will see the focus change

Comment: But when should I setfocus on the new tiny textbox?On click of the label that should hide it?

Comment: Are you hiding a label, a combobox or both?

Comment: On click of a particular label(which remains visible always) I am hiding the combobox. I think I can possible setfocus on the label itself when it is clicked so that the combobox loses focus?

Comment: I tried putting this in the on click event of the label:  "Me.label1.setfocus"  but it didn't work..the object setfocus is invalid..

Comment: You cannot set focus to an object that cannot receive focus, such as a label. A textbox is ideal. The code I posted is tested code. Why do you not wish to use a command button for this action? A command button receives focus when it is clicked, so there is no need for fancy footwork.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I recently just ran into a similar issue (and this post was in the first 4 or 5 results). If the control you're trying to disable is the first on the subform, try setting its Tab Index to 1, not 0. As soon as the subform gets the focus, the first control on it does, too. I was trying to set this during a Form_Open event, and this solved it.

Answer (score -1):

Rather than setting focus to any particular control, which may cause maintenance issues in the future if the controls on the form change, if you simulate a key press of Tab then focus will move to the next object in the tab order.

```
SendKeys "{TAB}"
DoEvents
Me.Command4.Visible = False
```

Note the doevents is necessary to allow the processing of the Tab.

Comment: The same question again: where do I put this code? I tried putting it in the on click event of the label which hides the combobox.I got the same error.Can't hide the control which is in focus.

Comment: SendKeys is almost never a good idea. It does not work on Vista without a bit of messing about and I imagine in is the same with Windows 7.

Comment: Yes.Finally I realized that cannot work.I should have used a command button maybe and I can't hide a control that has focus.I am now using the same combobox to display different records on click of the labels.